# Default /logout does not work if /login is customised spring security 5.7.11

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway

Below is my security config:

```
public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http){

    http
            .authorizeExchange(authorizeExchangeSpec ->
                authorizeExchangeSpec
                        .pathMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                        .anyExchange().authenticated()
                        .and()
                        .formLogin().disable()
                        .csrf().disable()
                        .oauth2Login())
            .exceptionHandling(exceptionHandlingSpec ->
            exceptionHandlingSpec.authenticationEntryPoint(new RedirectServerAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login")));
    return http.build();

}
```

I have a customized login page which works fine, and when i access the application, the custom login page is rendered. But, now when I try to logout form the application, using /logout GET call, it does not work. If I remove the custom login page configuration:

```
exceptionHandling(exceptionHandlingSpec ->
            exceptionHandlingSpec.authenticationEntryPoint(new RedirectServerAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login")))
```

And then try /logout GET call from the client, it works fine and default spring security behavior is seen for logout, where the call redirects to logout confirmation page and a logout button is displayed.

But after customization, the above default behavior is not working, looking at the logs I can see the spring security expects /logout to be POST call:

```
DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.u.m.PathPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher - Request 'GET /logout' doesn't match 'POST /logout'
27-03-2024 11:34:19.553 [reactor-http-nio-8] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.u.m.OrServerWebExchangeMatcher - No matches found
```

This authentication mechanism is implemented into a gateway, and I can't have a post call in gateway application, how do I get the GET /logout (default spring-secuirty) behavior to work.

I tried the configuration as suggested in the spring secuirty doc:[OIDC-Logout](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.7-SNAPSHOT/reactive/oauth2/login/advanced.html#webflux-oauth2-login-advanced-oidc-logout), but as spring expects POST call, I am unable to get the logout to work, the session is not getting removed in gateway application nor is the RP-Initiated logout working through `logoutSuccessHandler`

Comment: I have followed the [link]https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.7-SNAPSHOT/reactive/oauth2/login/advanced.html doc to customize login page.

Comment: `it does not work.` is an aweful way of describing what happens. Were are your logs, describe what happens. It doesnt work says nothing.

Comment: @Toerktumlare Added additional context as suggested.